# Fixed element during scrolling with top/bottom limits

Tags: scroll, position, fixed

I have an element (Google Map) to the right of another DIV element..

When I scroll the page, the page (results, map..etc) all scroll together.  When the map element/container is at the top.. I stop scrolling it, and set the CSS position property to fixed.

So far this has worked great...

However..  I noticed that if I had my browser window far short/small in HEIGHT...(just happened to have it sized like that for no good reason)..  and then I scroll.. the map will actually overlap/cover my footer content.

Here is my current snippet of jQuery that does my scrolling (applying classes to the map container element)

```
$(function(){           
        var stickyMapTop = $('#mapContainer').offset().top;  
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
            //console.log("View Port Size Check: "+viewportWidth);
            if(viewportWidth > 1024){
                //console.log("More than 768px width, ok to 'sticky'!");
                if($(window).scrollTop() > stickyMapTop) {
                    $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', left: $('#mapContainer').offset().left});
                } else {
                    $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                }
            }else{
                //do nothing
                //console.log("Less than 768px width sucka!");
                $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
            }
        });
      });
```

works fine/great as is..  but if I have my browser window re-sized for a small HEIGHT (not width)...  you can see that things scroll over/beyond/overlap the footer content.

Is there a bottom threshold or some other conditional check I can do to prevent this?

Goal:
I like how it works now.. I just want to ensure that it can NOT overlap the footer content ever..

maybe something like: (pseudo code)

```
var stickyMapBottom = (Bottom of DIV: (directory) - mapContainer Height);
```

(so the bottom of the mapContainer can not scroll beyond the bottom of the directoryContainer)

then something like:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > stickyMapTop && $(window).scrollTop() < stickyMapBottom){
```

.....etc..etc..

thoughts? trouble I am not seeing/understanding?  maybe I'm just barking up the wrong tree with this?

Here is my real world attempt:

```
//sticky map placement
        $(function(){           
            var stickyMapTop = $('#mapContainer').offset().top;  
            var stickyMapBottom = ($('#directory').offset().top + $('#directory').outerHeight())  - ($('#mapContainer').outerHeight() + 43);

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                console.log("TOP THRESHOLD: "+stickyMapTop);
                console.log("BOTTOM THRESHOLD: "+stickyMapBottom);
                console.log("CURRENT POS: "+$(window).scrollTop());
                var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
                //console.log("View Port Size Check: "+viewportWidth);
                if(viewportWidth > 1024){
                    //console.log("More than 768px width, ok to 'sticky'!");
                    if($(window).scrollTop() > stickyMapTop && $(window).scrollTop() < stickyMapBottom) {
                        $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', left: $('#mapContainer').offset().left});
                    } else {
                        //$('#mapContainer').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                        $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'static', top: $('#mapContainer').offset().top});
                    }
                }else{
                    //do nothing
                    //console.log("Less than 768px width sucka!");
                    $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                }
            });
          });
```

Its closer... and it no longer covers/overlaps the footer content..

however, when I reach the bottom threshold.. it sets the position to static again with top:0..   which I changed to offset().top.. thinking it would just leave it where it is/was currently at.. until I scroll back up.  getting lost.. do I need a secondary conditional check here:

```
else {
    //$('#mapContainer').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
    $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'static', top: $('#mapContainer').offset().top});
}
```

to see what new positioning style to apply perhaps?

Anybody?.. or is this another dead post?

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody bothered to answer...   I worked through it myself. (thanks)..  but for other who may be working through the same problems..

here is my solution/answer to add TOP and BOTTOM threshold your fixed element scroll with (or stay 'fixed' within I guess is more appropriate)..

```
//sticky map placement
        $(function(){           
            var stickyMapTop = $('#mapContainer').offset().top;  
            var stickyMapBottom = ($('#directory').offset().top + $('#directory').outerHeight())  - ($('#mapContainer').outerHeight(true));         
            var directoryBottom = stickyMapBottom - stickyMapTop + (parseInt($('#mapContainer').css("marginTop").replace('px', '')));

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
                if(viewportWidth > 1024){
                    if($(window).scrollTop() > stickyMapTop && $(window).scrollTop() < stickyMapBottom) {
                        $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', left: $('#mapContainer').offset().left});
                    }else{
                        //original
                        //$('#mapContainer').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                        if($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyMapBottom) {
                            //secondary position check to see what new positioning style to apply?  
                            $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'relative', top: directoryBottom, left:'0px'});
                        }else if($(window).scrollTop() < stickyMapTop){ 
                            //needed?
                            $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                        }                   
                    }
                }else{
                    $('#mapContainer').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                }
            });
          });
```

hope it helps someone else. :)